# EF lazy loading does not work with splitted entity using DB views

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I tried using entity splitting in order to extend my entities with properties gathered from a database view. This works just fine if I load the splitted entity directly, but it does not work if I have an entity to wich the splitted entity is connected through navigation properties.

Let's roughly say it looks like this
[Entity A]-[Entity B]-[Entity C]

If Entity C is not splitted I can get me Entity A and navigate through Entity B to Entity C which ist done through navigationproperties using lazy loading (as far as I understand it). This works like a charm.

If Entity C is a splitted Entity containing Data out of an DB Table and a DB View then the above described navigation from Entity A to Entity C returns null. On the other Hand, if I load Entity C directly it gets fully loaded containing both, the data of the DB Table as well as the data of the DB View.

Is there something special that I did not think of?

Answer (score 0):

Here is an article by Gil Fink that might help.

http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/gilf/archive/2009/03/06/entity-splitting-in-entity-framework.aspx

> If Entity C is a splitted Entity containing Data out of an DB Table and a DB View then the above described navigation from Entity A to Entity C returns null. On the other Hand, if I load Entity C directly it gets fully loaded containing both, the data of the DB Table as well as the data of the DB View.

What you say sounds right. If you split the table properly then those properties would no longer be available in Entity C.

If you don't need the properties from Entity C "all the time", then your first mapping scenario should suffice.

Comment: thanks for your answer. It was not the solution for my problem but the article in your link helped me to understand that the inner join relation was the problem

Answer (score 0):

My problem was the fact that, splitted entities get connected through a inner join (see discussion here http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/adonetefx/thread/237c1de4-7a42-4c3f-80ab-16601e7fadac/ ) what I expected was something like a left join so that properties out of an additional table get added if they exist and ignored if not. In fact if there is no entry in the additional table, then the whole entity does not get initialized.

The above described problem with lazy loading was just a coincidence because on the one hand i loaded an entity containing aditional properties and on the other hand an entity that did not and therefore did not even get initialized as described before.